# Accessory Type in UITableViewCell subclass is not visible

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm doing everything programmatically. I have a UITableView with its rows being a UITableViewCell subclass. I have been unable to set the accessoryType of my cell as nothing appears on the screen. Later on I want to be able to select a cell, and add a checkmark when selected.

```
class ContactsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    let name = UILabel()
    let phoneNumber = UILabel()
    let iPADFACTOR:CGFloat = DeviceHelper().isIPAD ? 1.4: 1.0

    var rowSelected = false

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        phoneNumber.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)
        phoneNumber.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        self.contentView.addSubview(name)
        self.contentView.addSubview(phoneNumber)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {

        let margeV:CGFloat = 5.0*iPADFACTOR
        let margeH = self.frame.width*0.05

        name.frame = CGRectMake(margeH, margeV, self.frame.width - margeH * 4, 18)
        phoneNumber.frame = CGRectMake(margeH, name.frame.maxY + 5, self.frame.width - margeH * 4, 15)
    }

}
```

As you can see I'm using the `layoutSubviews()` method, to set the frame of my labels and I've tried playing with the label size to check if somehow it was hiding the accessoryView without success. I've even tried setting their frame to 0.

I'm also not sure if I'm setting my frames correctly. Should I use `self.contentView.frame` instead of `self.frame` ?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: can u check width of the cell and tableview

Comment: write cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark inside cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: Can you show the code of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Maybe you should invoke `super.layoutSubviews()` in `override func layoutSubviews()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    let margeV:CGFloat = 5.0*iPADFACTOR
    let margeH = self.frame.width*0.05

    name.frame = CGRectMake(margeH, margeV, self.frame.width - margeH * 4, 18)
    phoneNumber.frame = CGRectMake(margeH, name.frame.maxY + 5, self.frame.width - margeH * 4, 15)
}
```

Comment: That was it thanks a lot. I don't know how I forgot to reference the superclass. Apart from that do you know if it's better to use the contentView to position my subviews?

Comment: @CroiSciento When you addSubview, you had better use contentView.In this case, use contentView to compute subviews frame.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (YES) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
} else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None;
}
```